# Providing configuration for existing plugins in maven lifecycle mapping

Tags: plugins, compiler-construction, maven, packaging, lifecycle

I would like to provide a maven plugin with a custom `<packaging>` that provides a complex lifecycle.  As part of this lifecycle, I need to run the maven-compiler-plugin 2 times in different phases with different configurations.  I would like to make this packaging as simple as possible to use.  The goal would be that all a consumer of this plugin would have to do is select the new packaging and not have to do any plugin execution configuration:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some.other.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>something-useful</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>my-maven-plugin-jar</packaging>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions
      </plugin>
    </plugin>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then my custom lifecycle would bind the all the goals I needed including the compiler both times.  The problem is, each compiler pass is compiling different source (using `<includes> and <excludes>` into different destinations (using outputDirectory) and I cant find any way to configure them without doing so in the `<executions>` sub-element of pom using my plugin.  I could do this with an archetype, but it seems to me to be a little more elegant to do this with a custom packaging.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've asked essentially the same thing [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036550/maven-plugin-change-default-mojo-configuration-in-lifecycle-mapping).