# Change default mojo configuration in lifecycle mapping

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven 3 plugin which builds plugins for another application. A plugin is basically a JAR file with some fancy manifests. The compiled classes need to be post-processed for the plugin to work with the production build of the host application. Unfortunately, the processed version of the plugin won't work with the debug build of the host. I therefore need to produce two artifacts: the raw classes with the classifier `debug` and the post-processed version as the main artifact.

I've got a working Maven plugin which defines a new packaging type with its own lifecycle mappings. In order to create the `debug` artifact, though, I need to call `jar:jar` with the `classifier` property set. I haven't been able to find a way to change the configuration for a Mojo execution from a lifecycle mapping. Is that even possible? Will I have to make everyone use a super POM provided with my plugin?

For reference, here's the relevant part of my `components.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <!-- snip other components, including ArtifactHandler -->
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
      <role-hint>my-packaging</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycles>
          <lifecycle>
            <id>default</id>
            <phases>
              <!-- snip other phases -->
              <package>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar
              </package>
            </phases>
          </lifecycle>
        </lifecycles>
      </configuration>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

I need the execution to be equivalent to this POM fragment:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>debug-jar</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goal>jar</goal>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>debug</classifier>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I found [one SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218769/providing-configuration-for-existing-plugins-in-maven-lifecycle-mapping) that seems to be the same thing I'm looking for but it doesn't have any answers. [This is the documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/08/create-a-customized-build-process-in-maven/) that I used to create the lifecycle mapping in the first place. Heavy Googling hasn't turned up anything that seems related, but I'm having trouble coming up with sufficiently specific search terms.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just invoke the 'archiver' component from your plugin as an ordinary subroutine, as opposed to forking an execution of the jar plugin?

Comment: @bmargulies I'm not forking a lifecycle from a Mojo. This is a lifecycle mapping associated with a custom packaging type. For projects using the packaging it's the default lifecycle. I could create a wrapper Mojo that invokes the archiver if I have to, but that removes the user's ability to override that part of the configuration so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Hmm. I'd pose this on one of the maven mailing lists.

Comment: @SamHanes did You ever get this resolved? I'm working on a simpler issue myself and still struggling with this.  The closest I've found is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven/1427749

Comment: @Raystorm no, unfortunately not. I'm still just using a wrapper mojo that calls the archiver from Java with the necessary parameters, plus documentation on how to replace that with the actual archiver for users that need custom parameters. If you find a better solution please do post an answer.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new goal that just wraps the  [Mojo Executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) plugin to call jar:jar with the classifier property you need set.